# How to control obscured fields on background with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, background-process, flutter-getx, obscured-view

I am developing an app with Flutter/Dart and GetX. I have a boolean variable named "obscureText". When this variable is true, specific text fields' inputs are all visible. When this variable is false, specific text field's inputs are all obscured. (like '*****'). What I want is that when user exits from app via home button or task mode, app is running on background right? When app enters background mode, i want "obscureText" variable to be false automaticly. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [WidgetsBindingObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) to detect a change of `AppLifecycleState` and update your value when the state is `paused`.

Comment: Thank you for this advice but can you share a example code for this? For my situation.